# Несколько RewriteRule для одного набора условий RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Не работает второй RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mod/([0-9]+)/?$ /mod.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Если поменять местами, то не работает ни тот, ни тот.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала проверяется `RewriteRule`, потом проверяются `RewriteCond` перед ним. Несколько `RewriteRule` к одному набору `RewriteCond`, вообще говоря, не предполагаются.

Но вы можете воспользоватсья опцией `S|skip`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mod/([0-9]+)/?$ /mod.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Правило `RewriteRule .* -` срабатывает всегда, поэтому всегда проверяются условия (обратите внимание, что теперь там отрицание исходного выражения: "файл ИЛИ директория" вместо "НЕ файл И НЕ директория"). И, если условия выполняются (то есть запрашивается файл или директория), то последующие правила пропускаются. В противном случае проверяются регулярные выражения в последующих двух правилах.

См. [Applying RewriteCond to Multiple RewriteRule in .htaccess](http://www.sant-media.co.uk/2010/03/applying-rewritecond-to-multiple-rewriterule-in-htaccess/).

**[Добавлено]**

Правило

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

приводит к бесконечной рекурсии. Можно ограничить множество допустимых символов, чтобы сам скрипт php не попадал в условие, например:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\./]*)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.